# How to add e.g. 5 elements to a 10 rows listview in android?

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I am previously working on PHP and js , and recently I am working on android listview
However, I encountered a problem in creating a custom adapter for listview

```
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO
        if (arg1 == null) {
            arg1 = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid, arg2, false);
        }
        TextView name = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView desc = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        if (arg0 < images.length) {
            image.setImageResource(images[arg0]);
        }
        name.setText(names[arg0]);
        desc.setText(description[arg0]);
        return arg1;
    }
```

The problem is I have 3 array of content to pass to the listview grid, for the first two array, there are 10 element and the last one have 5 only. So , it is out of boundries for the last one. I added a condition to check whether it exceed 5 , but args0 seems not increased according to the row?

```
if (arg0 < images.length) {
                image.setImageResource(images[arg0]);
            }
```

The first five row and some other rows also has image setted,  why is that and how to fix this? thanks

Comment: (1) how are the arrays being used? Are you trying to display all the data from all 3 at the same time? Or just 1 at a time? (2) args0 in your set up is the position of the object so how would it ever be outside the length of the array you were passing in?

Comment: Thanks for reply.eg. the first two array are name and gender, and the last array is photo of the member, there are 10 memebrs but only the first 5 memebers has photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In General**

since you want to display `Data` to your list, plx create an Object that represents Data.

like you named in your comment above:

```
public class ListEntry {
  String name = "";
  String gender = "";//use enum here perhaps -.-
  String photoUrl = null; //or use byte[] photo or whatever you've stored in your array before
  // write getters/setters for your members
}
```

then you can use *one* array `ListEntry[]` (or List<ListEntry>) to access all data. this way you get around your indexOutOfBoundsException.

lookup any listadapter tutorials online, e.g. the one from [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/)

**Why do more than the first five entries have an image?**

Androids Adapters for Listviews implement a caching mechanism to reduce the inflating (performance/memory cost intensive) of new list-items (e.g. rows) to a minimum. therefore there are only as many rows (or little more) created as displayed by the list. since you only set images if there are any, but never remove already set images from rows, you result in some rows that replay images they shouldn't. these rows are cached from previously outscrolling rows.

therefore add something like

```
if (listItem.photo != null) {
  image.setImageResource(images[arg0]);
} else {
  image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

as reference for listviews and their caching mechanism see [Romain Guy on ListViews](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

**Edit Regarding usage of Listadapter**

The `getView(..)` you posted above is inside your `ListAdapter` implementation, prefarrably you've extended an `ArrayAdapter<T>`.  if so, your `T` should now state `ListEntry` and you have any line of code that states

`MyArrayAdapter myAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter()` or something like that.

now you have an array or List of ListEntry like `List<ListEntry> myCollection = new ArrayList<ListEntry>()` or `ListEntry[] listEntries = new ListEntry[10]` and use

`myAdapter.addAll(listEntries);`

to get an item of your list inside your `getView(..)` you can use:

`ListEntry currentEntry = getItem(arg0);`

and refer the single members of currentEntry to set them ;-)

Comment: Sorry I am new to this , I have created a new class ListEntry, how can I set the ListEntry array ?

Comment: @user782104 edited my anwer to fit your needs, hope it helps, else invite me to chat ;-)

Comment: yes. I have created a room call "asdasfsdgfdsgdfg" , would you mind join?

Comment: Thanks for your explaination

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
if (images[arg0] != null) image.setImageResource(images[arg0]);
```

?

Comment: not working, still java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5